# Difference between React and React Native

Tags: reactjs

I have to develop some web projects, and in theory, I know React is good way of developing website perfectly, but not sure if I have to use React or React Native.

I tried to use React.js but don't know how to start.

Anybody help me for my humble question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of React guy, I want to suggest some tips on react world.

React native is mobile development framework which is supported by facebook, and you can start by using RN tutorial - https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.

React.js is web development library which is using by Javascript or Typescript.
You can start by looking at React doc - https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html.

I know you were in other tech world, but if you spend some time on them, you can be familiar soon.

Comment: Those two tutorials are good to start as I can see. Can you recommend other things for react and react native since I am completely starter?

Comment: After looking at them, you should dive in to react world to learn professional tips and technologies. of course, by looking at github or so, you can get much more information about react including react libraries.